# in phantomjs,how to create a filesystem variable within the page context

Tags: javascript, file, phantomjs

While creating a filesystem variable within the page context in the phantomjs script for the below code,the following error is found:

Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

How to solve the same??

CODE::

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs=require('fs');

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg);
};

page.onError = function(msg) {
  console.log('ERROR MESSAGE: ' + msg);
};

var filters;

page.open(url, function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function(filters) {
      var fs = require('fs');
      var stream = fs.open('outputs.txt');
      var v1 = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for(var i=0;i < v1.length; ++i)   
      { 
        //some operation
        console.log(temp);
      }
      stream.close();
    },fs);
    phantom.exit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to write from a webpage to user's disk directly, imagine how easy it would be to infect a computer otherwise.

Instead return an array with necessary elements back to PhantomJS context and write to disk there.